# how to call event handler from jqGrid select custom formatter

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid with a dropdown. I am filling the dropdown with "custom formatter"(`dropDownFormatter1`) value.I am getting that, but as per the `onchange` i need to do some functionality. My main question is how to add the `onchange` event in my below code.

Here is my code:

```js
$("#grid").jqGrid({
    url: bookingStatusurl,
    datatype: "json",
    shrinkToFit: true,
    colModel: [
        { name: 'BookingStatusID', index: ''BookingStatusID'', hidden: true,
            key: true },
        { name: 'BookingStatus', index: 'BookingStatus', width: 260,
            sortable: false },
        { name: 'NumberOfBooking ', index: 'NumberOfBooking', width: 300,
            sortable: false, align: 'right', formatter: 'currency',
            formatoptions: { prefix: "Number Of Booking: "} },
        { name: 'SortOrderType', index: 'SortOrderType', align: 'right',
            edittype: 'select', formatter: **dropDownFormatter1** }
        //As per the on change of my dropDownFormatter1 by subgrid need to change.
    ],
    rowNum: 40,
    rowList: [40, 80, 120]
    //sortname: 'id',
    viewrecords: true,
    //sortorder: "desc",
    autowidth: true,
    multiselect: false,
    shrinkToFit: true,
    height: 'auto',
    altRows: true,
    subGrid: true,
    //loadonce: false,
    //caption: "Pipeline By Booking Status",
    subGridRowExpanded: function (subgrid_id, row_id) {}
});
```

Here is the code for cutom formatter:

```js
function dropDownFormatter1(cellvalue, options, rowObject, action) {
   // var statusTypeId = rowObject[0];
    return '<label>Sort Order:</label>' +
        '<select>' +
            '<option value="asc">asc</option>' +
            '<option value="desc">desc</option>' +
        '</select>';
}
```

Please help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to implement `onchange` callback would be to add `onchange` attribute in the HTML code which generate your `dropDownFormatter1` formatter. You can for example define on the **global** level your custom JavaScript function

```
var myOnChangeFormatter1Callback = function (event) {
        var $select = $(this), $tr = $select.closest('tr.jqgrow');

        alert ("the select in the row with id=" + $tr.id +
               " are changed to the option" + $select.val());
    };
```

To call `myOnChangeFormatter1Callback` from the `onchange` one can modify `dropDownFormatter1` to the following

```
function dropDownFormatter1(cellvalue, options, rowObject, action) {
   // var statusTypeId = rowObject[0];
    return '<label>Sort Order:</label>' +
        '<select onchange="myOnChangeFormatter1Callback.call(this, arguments[0]);">' +
            '<option value="asc">asc</option>' +
            '<option value="desc">desc</option>' +
        '</select>';
}
```

Typically events will be called with `event` as the name of the first parameter (ad the only) parameter, but in some browsers one should use `windows.event` instead. So to be more compatible one should use `event || windows.event` or use just `arguments[0]` like I did.

If you don't like to define function with `var myOnChangeFormatter1Callback = function (...` and will use `function myOnChangeFormatter1Callback (...` you will be *unable to forward `this`* inside of the function at list in strict mode of JavaScript execution. In the case you should forward `this` as additional parameter and use `"myOnChangeFormatter1Callback(this, arguments[0]);"` instead of `"myOnChangeFormatter1Callback.call(this, arguments[0]);"`. The prototype of `myOnChangeFormatter1Callback` should be changed from `var myOnChangeFormatter1Callback = function (event) {...}` to `function myOnChangeFormatter1Callback (myObj, event) {...}`.

Comment: Thanks Oleg.As usual you rocks.